# query select the div which is not clicked to increase its width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

So i have two boxes type structure adjacent to each other,
i want to animate the box which i clicked and increase its width , while other box should just move to right side when that transitions is taking place

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mt-5">
  <a href="project1.html" class="active hovereffect">
   <div class="overlay">
     <h2 class="title">Projects 1</h2>
   </div>
   </a>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mt-5">
   <a href="project2.html" class="hovereffect">
     <div class="overlay">
        <h2 class="title">Projects 2</h2>
     </div>
    </a>
 </div>
```

The div which i clicked should increase the width and other should just slide

```
   $(lastElementClicked).animate({width:900})
```

// i want this to be working to select div which is not clicked

```
   var a = $(lastElementClicked).find('col-md-6:not(:click)');
   $(a).animate(slideleft)
```

any idea how can i queryselect the div which is not clicked.

Comment: Assuming they are wrapped, `var a = $(lastElementClicked).siblings();` could be an option: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `.siblings()` method as [LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) had suggested, but if you want to achieve it in your own way, then the following illustrates a possible way.

```js
var notClicked = null;

$('.col-md-6').on('click', function() {
  $('.col-md-6').each((index, value) => {
    if(value !== this) notClicked = value;
  });
  
  console.log($(notClicked).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mt-5">
  <a href="#" class="active hovereffect">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="title">Projects 1</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mt-5">
  <a href="#" class="hovereffect">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="title">Projects 2</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```